# Least upper bound property question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $E \subset S$ and $S$ does not have the least-upper-bound property. Suppose also that $E$ is bounded above and non-empty. Then we cannot say that $E$ does not have a least-upper bound right?

I am asking this question because $Z \subset R$ and $Z \subset Q$ where $Z$ is a certain set of integers (e.g. {1,2,3,4,5}), $R$ is the real number set while $Q$ is the rational number set. We know that $R$ has the least-upper-bound property while $Q$ does not. Since $Z \subset R$, $Z$ has a least upper bound if it is non-empty and bounded above. This is despite the fact that it is a subset of $Q$ which does not have the least-upper-bound property.

Hence is it true that being a subset of a set without the least-upper-bound property does not say anything but being a subset of a set with the least-upper-bound property definitely means that that set has a least upper bound if it is not empty and bounded above?

Comment: In any totally ordered set $S$, for every $s\in S$, the set $\{x\in S : x \leqslant s\}$ has a least upper bound. Yes, even if $S$ does not have the least upper bound property, some subsets have a least upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

All that is required for a function to fail to satisfy the least upper bound property is for one subset to fail to have a supremum. That is, failing to satisfy the l.u.b.p. does not mean that all subsets lack suprema, just that some do.

So, yes. $E$ can have a least upper bound, even if $S$ doesn't. For example, consider the complex numbers under the lexicographic order, and the reals as a subset. The reals have the l.u.b.p., but the complex numbers do not.